# Can anyone provide some information on "-webkit" in css files?

Tags: css

I could see some css lines like below in one of the tutorials of css.

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
-moz-transform: translateY(0px);
-ms-transform: translateY(0px);
-o-transform: translateY(0px);
transform: translateY(0px);
```

Could you please explain?

Comment: they are called `vendor prefixes`, you can find more info about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any CSS property that includes `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-ms-` and `-o-` is a CSS extension that is supported by these given browser engines.

So the code you've provided will work across most available browsers.

`-webkit-` - would be support browsers such as Safari or Google Chrome

`-moz-` - would be supported by Firefox

`-o-` - would be supported by Opera

`-ms-` - would be supported by Internet Explorer browsers